# Working with passed data between forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Currently in my windows form, I have a few WinForms to work with. One WinForm acts as a main menu and is supposed to call another form as a secondary window on its own.

```
Private Sub btnMainGame_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMainGame.Click
    ' This is the button to call up the main game controller. So simply hide this form aned then open the new form.

    Dim frmController As New frmControllerScreen

    frmController.Show()
    Me.Hide() ' Happens on .Close as well

End Sub
```

The above code invokes another WinForm which is used to handle more options. When the user clicks on a particular button, a sub form is created again.

```
    Dim OpenNewGameWindow As New frmGameConfig

    OpenNewGameWindow.ShowDialog(Me)
    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.None ' Used to prevent the subform from closing the main form when it catches a dialog result.
```

Now in the frmGameConfig, the program is supposed to take data and pass it back to the form that called it.

```
Private Sub btnNewGameStartGame_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewGameStartGame.Click
 ' ... Skipped code...
    frmControllerScreen.MasterQuestionList = QuestionList
    frmControllerScreen.blnBankedTime = cbBankedTime.Checked

 ' ... Skipped code...
End Sub
```

However, when the frmController tries to reference MasterQuestionList... it returns a nullreference error as if it was not set.

Here's where things get funny...

When I made this code, frmControllerScreen was actually the startup form. Now when I change this form back to frmMainMenu, I get `NullReference` errors constantly.

My question: How am I supposed to pass information from one form to the next form if it was instantiated from a parent form. (Note I even moved the declartion to Public as a "module-wide" variable... and nothing happens but the same result.) The same error happens even if I go ahead and declare `frmController.MasterQuestionList` as well.

Comment: Did you assign to `frmController` the `MdiParent` property to `this` i.e. your main form? Here is an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) and how do you declare `frmController.MasterQuestionList`?

Comment: @BassemAkl: I don't think MDI would fit into this as this isn't multiple forms loading into each one but rather multiple form windows instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to pass data back from the called form to the caller, you can reference the called form's controls from the calling code after .ShowDialog.

```
Dim OpenNewGameWindow As New frmGameConfig

If OpenNewGameWindow.ShowDialog() Then
    MasterQuestionList = OpenNewGameWindow.QuestionList
    blnBankedTime = OpenNewGameWindow.cbBankedTime.Checked
End If
```

In OpenGameWindow button click:

```
Private Sub btnNewGameStartGame_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewGameStartGame.Click
    Me.DialogResult = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm I'll give this a go and see what fits.

Comment: Remember, just because the window closed doesn't make it gone...not till it falls out of scope or it's Disposed, so once you instantiate it, everything in it is Friend, and therefore accessible.

Comment: Would I still been able to call a property with that in mind? I think that's where I have a problem at.

Comment: Once you invoke `New frmGameConfig` everything on the form is instantiated, and Form_Load fires, so yes, properties of controls, and of course form-level objects that aren't private, are accessible until you actually Dispose the form object.